# How to deploy the dotnet code to IIS using MSDeploy.exe

Tags: .net, msdeploy

I want to deploy the dotnet packaged code to IIS using MSdeploy.exe, and need to know how to configure a parameters file and use it to deploy the code.

Any link to related topics will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How-to documentation on Web Deploy is available on iis.net - http://www.iis.net/learn/publish

There's also reference-style documentation on Technet - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568996(v=ws.10).aspx

Finally, the skip rules can be a little confusing. I've written a blog post attempting to explain their nuances as well as I can - https://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/17/demystifying-msdeploy-skip-rules/

Comment: thnx for the links Richard